# Switching layouts in navigation drawer

Tags: java, android

I am using the navigation drawer example of andriod studio I got that feed up of xamrain I decided to take the plunge and learn java as I am a c# programmer its quite the same to me.

But I am having difcuility in the example app it has one content layout that loads when the app loads but I want to switch that in my OnNaviationItemSelected event to different layouts.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

My Question is I presume i need to use a layout with the same id of the drawer layout. Also How do I hook up my java class to the layout.

Comment: Why did you abandon xamarin? And, java developers, i'm a java developer for 4 years, moving to Kotlin, new job ads asking for Kotlin instead of java. You can check out android ads on SO and see for yourself.

Comment: Xamarin is just to unstable between builds

Comment: If you wish to switch layouts you should use fragments and replace fragment when an item on navigation drawer is touched. And instead of Navigation Drawer, i advise you to use Navigation View from design library.

Comment: I am trying to use the andriod studio example and it uses layouts so was sticking to that thanks

Comment: You can also use setContentView(R.layout.newLayout) bu it's less preferable than changing content using fragments. You should change needed section of your app using fragment transaction with replace command.

Comment: @Thracian if you could provide an answer using fragments I will use that apporach thanks